# Android layout doesn't "refresh" until I start a new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, layout

I have this problem. I wrote a program and I have this code in the MainActivity class:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
            startActivity(activity);
            output.setText(object.toString());
        }
    });
```

In AnotherActivity I modify the object and after that activity ends (with finish()) i want to "refresh" the textView of the MainActivity. 
At the end of AnotherActivity the object is actually modified, but the text is not refreshed. If I click again on button, before new Activity is started (with his layout) the text is refreshed as it should, and if I close the AnotherActivity layout, the text is well refreshed. But if I don't click again that button, the text remains the old one. How can I do? Sorry for bad English or bad explanation.

Comment: Try this: `output.invalidate()` after setText.

Comment: Please post the code that declares and initializes the object variable, as well as the code that changes it in AnotherActivity.

Comment: Sorry i have missed part about this. You can use startActivityForResult: http://tinyurl.com/bsrsmm7 and override onActivityResult to get the results.

Comment: Hi Egor, I declare and initialize as static in another class to be easily accessed by all my class. But the object is really modified (i tried with System.out.println) so I don't think it's that the problem! Krystian, thank you, I'm trying it.

Comment: I resolved it taking the output TextView in another class as static to setText directly in AnotherActivity before finish(). Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onResume()` in the first activity to update your UI when the second activity is finished.

Either that or start the second activity with [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) which will call [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) for you when the second activity is finished.